# Changing position of custom dialog

Tags: android

i am developing an application that needs to show dialog just below a menu button situated            at navigation bar, for achieving this i used below code

```
Dialog dialogMenu = new Dialog(mContext);
        dialogMenu.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_main_menu);
        dialogMenu.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

        WindowManager.LayoutParams windowLayout = dialogMenu.getWindow()
                .getAttributes();
        windowLayout.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
        dialogMenu.getWindow().getAttributes().verticalMargin = -0.8F;
        dialogMenu.getWindow().getAttributes().horizontalMargin = 0.02F;
        dialogMenu.getWindow().setAttributes(windowLayout);
```

But the problem is that after a fixed vertical margin dialog is not moving up as shown in image, actually i want dialog point should touch the menu button. I am not able to find the solution.
[image: image having screenshot of mydevice]

Here is my dialog_main_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/main_menu_bg" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtHeadingMenu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text="@string/menu"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ListItem_btnMyItem"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/txtHeadingMenu"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_btn_sort_dialog"
                android:text="@string/my_item"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ListItem_btnMyCategory"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/ListItem_btnMyItem"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_btn_sort_dialog"
                android:text="@string/my_category"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ListItem_btnPersonalList"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/ListItem_btnMyCategory"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_btn_sort_dialog"
                android:text="@string/personal_list"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ListItem_btnStore"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/ListItem_btnPersonalList"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_btn_sort_dialog"
                android:text="@string/store"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ListItem_btnSharedList"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/ListItem_btnStore"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_btn_sort_dialog"
                android:text="@string/shared_list"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ListItem_btnSettings"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/ListItem_btnSharedList"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_btn_sort_dialog"
                android:text="@string/settings"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="13sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what is yours layout??? you can also use quickaction for this purpose visit https://github.com/evancharlton/quick-actions-demo

Comment: @ Jitesh Upadhyay: does dialog_layout.xml can help in making position change of dialog?

Comment: have you tried changing the vertical margin. ?

Comment: Also try shuffling with the layout margin of the resources

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same thing by applying

```
windowLayout.x = (put values according to your requirement)  // and 
windowLayout.y=(put values according to your requirement) 
//and ignore using 
dialogMenu.getWindow().getAttributes().verticalMargin = -0.8F;
dialogMenu.getWindow().getAttributes().horizontalMargin = 0.02F;
```

Comment: i had also tried with x and y parameters but after a fixed value of y dialog is not moving up.